# Why doesn't work substitution for symbolic matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I've created a matrix(or vector) that its members are symbolic expressions(its name is A). when i try to substitute `x0 = [500 550 500 500 450 500 555 450]'` instead of `x = [x3 x4 x5 x6 y3 y4 y5 y6]'`  nothing happens. class of `x0` is `double` and class of `x` is `sym`.
this is my code:

```
      A =                                               conj(((x3 - 500)^2 + (y3 - 300)^2)^(1/2))
                                                        conj(((x4 - 500)^2 + (y4 - 300)^2)^(1/2))
                                                        conj(((x5 - 500)^2 + (y5 - 300)^2)^(1/2))
 conj(((y3 - 8623888390675025/17592186044416)^2 + (x3 - 1591228181075565/4398046511104)^2)^(1/2))
 conj(((y4 - 8623888390675025/17592186044416)^2 + (x4 - 1591228181075565/4398046511104)^2)^(1/2))
 conj(((y5 - 8623888390675025/17592186044416)^2 + (x5 - 1591228181075565/4398046511104)^2)^(1/2))
                                                        conj(((x3 - x4)^2 + (y3 - y4)^2)^(1/2))
                                                        conj(((x3 - x5)^2 + (y3 - y5)^2)^(1/2))
                                                        conj(((x4 - x5)^2 + (y4 - y5)^2)^(1/2))
                                                        conj(((x6 - 500)^2 + (y6 - 300)^2)^(1/2))
 conj(((y6 - 8623888390675025/17592186044416)^2 + (x6 - 1591228181075565/4398046511104)^2)^(1/2))
                                                        conj(((x3 - x6)^2 + (y3 - y6)^2)^(1/2))
                                                        conj(((x4 - x6)^2 + (y4 - y6)^2)^(1/2))
                                                        conj(((x5 - x6)^2 + (y5 - y6)^2)^(1/2))


    for j = 1:length(x)
        A = subs(A,x(j),x0(j))
    end
```

what should i do?

Comment: That can't be all of your code? Most of this isn't compilable Matlab...

Comment: Yes,It is a piece of my code. I defined x0 and x first. To determine of x i first used syms x3 x4 x5 x6 y3 y4 y5 y6. i can't sub x0 rather than x in A

Comment: All of my code is very much and i can't write here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all answers, i found my answer. i'm using below loop and it is working well. note : to avoid `'conj'` in all of code i used  `.'`  rather than `'` to get transpose of a matrix.
this link was very useful :[simbolic-toolbox-how-to-avoid-conj-in-matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/24846-simbolic-toolbox-how-to-avoid-conj-in-matrix)

```
    for i = 1:numel(A)
            A(i) = subs(A(i),x,x0);
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

you could not assign value to symbolic matrices in  that way,

```
syms a b c 
x=[a b c]
x=
  [a, b, c]
```

when you set value for x just x itself change :

```
x=[1,2,3]
x=
  [1,2,3]
```

test:

```
eval(a)
ans=
   a
```

so when you change x value , just value of x itself changing (not a b and c)

you must assign value to a b and c separately

```
a=1; b=2; c=3;
eval(x)
ans=
  [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: thanks but it works like this:
`syms a b c; 
x=[a b c];
a =1; b=2; c=3;
x
x =
[ a, b, c]`

Comment: @mahdin75 i updated the answer , you should use function eval() to see evaluation of x

Comment: thanks so much, i use your idea to solve and when i solve that i'll say you